# Shneim Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twelve?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Sarah was 15 ([Y.S. 16:78](http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/lechlecha.html)) when she married and 127 when she died, Sarah was married to Avraham for 112 years.

Answer (score 6):

112 were the accompaniers of עַמִּינָדָב (*Divre Hayamim* I 15:10).

Answer (score 5):

112 were the descendants of יוֹרָה (Ezra 2:18).

Answer (score 4):

According to Rashi in Vzos HaBracha Rabbi Yehuda holds that the last eight Pesukim in the Torah were written by Yehoshua. Those 8 Pesukim = 112 words.

Answer (score 4):

112 pesukim in Parshas Vayeishev.
112 words in Mizmor Shir L'yom HaShabbos.

Comment: Yaacov, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this answer! I hope you'll look around the site and find other information you like, perhaps including our questions on [tag:mikeitz] or [tag:chanuka]. lease consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

Parshas Matos has 112 Pesukim

Answer (score 2):

112 are the *dapim* in *Sanhedrin*.